# Route with infinite number of segments in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to route any link, which starts with "/app/" segment, to one controller action. URL examples:

```
http://localhost/app/
http://localhost/app/something
http://localhost/app/something/something2
http://localhost/app/something/something2/..../somethingN
```

I need to route these all urls to one controller action. How to do it in Laravel 5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could lump all the parameters into 1 variable by using a regular expression constraint

`Route::get('app/{parameters?}', 'HomeController@app')->where('parameters', '.*');`

The $parameters variable will then be populated with whatever goes after app (eg. "something/something2", "something/something2/something3", etc). You can then parse this out however you need.